# Cloud build trigger fails to execute and returns no detailed explanation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to run a build trigger on [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build) but for some reason it returns an error which doesn't really mean a lot.

> ERROR: INTERNAL: Internal error encountered.

No matter if I run it through the UI in GCP console or I run it through a shell script via [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell). Is it possible to see more detailed explanation of why is this happening? I have exactly the same trigger configured on another environment (project) and it works as expected.

Comment: I think it's a Google Internal error. You can share your config if you want a check by the community, or open a case to the support. If you haven't paid support, you can open an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/) (answer delay not guaranteed)

Comment: What config? Do you mean cloudbuild.yaml?

Comment: Yes, your cloud build configuration that fail